# Sharp Aquos Crystal

Tags: rooting, root-access

Does anyone know about the Sharp Aquos Crystal cell phone? Can this phone be rooted? As far as I know, no one knows how to root this device.

Answer (score 0):

Sharp phones are known to be notoriously hard to root and tinker with. Tewilove from [our local forums [WARNING: Chinese]](http://tieba.baidu.com/p/4205577794?pn=1) have made limited progress but all links are down for now (seems like someone else is trying to sell this for money). I don't know if [this XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/aquos-crystal/general/temp-root-306sh-t3129456) (also posted by him) is still up-to-date, but since this one is more accessible, you might want to take a look.